# Baby Rudin 2.38

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $I_n$ is a sequence of intervals in R1 such that  $I_n⊃I_{n+1}$.

Prove
$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty I_n \neq\varnothing$

> Considering $I_n = (a_n,b_n)$ $[\dots]$ If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers then
>
> $$a_n ≤ a_{m+n} ≤ b_{m+n} ≤ b_m$$

Why is $b_{n+m}≤ b_m$?

Shouldn't the opposite be true?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please supply the context of this. People are not usually inclined to look into a book for the context, and hence won't be able to help you.

Comment: Please copy the entire paragraph, this question is useless for future readers otherwise.

Comment: I thought $I_n$ was some interval, but it turns out to be a partition.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format correctly but i have edited

Comment: Grand_chat answered my question. I was wondering by b_m was greater than b_(n+m) since if n,m>0 n+m > m. but as  In⊃In+1 the right endpoints form a decreasing sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption, $I_n\supset I_{n+1}$ for each $n$. This means that intervals with larger subscript are contained inside intervals with smaller subscript, which means the left endpoints form an increasing sequence and the right endpoints form a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that! You guys sure do answer quick.